# Duda sobre una composicion UML y sus entidades

Tags: sql, uml

Hola muy buenas estoy realizando un diagrama de clases y tengo una duda muy importante, se me pide:

> Cada evento deportivo es organizado por una única entidad, si bien una entidad puede organizar varios eventos deportivos. Cada entidad tendrá asignado un código alfanumérico único y también se desea almacenar su nombre y su página web, en caso de que disponga de ella. Puede ocurrir que un evento deportivo tenga una o varias entidades que lo patrocinen, aunque también es posible que haya eventos que carezcan de patrocinador. Por otro lado, una entidad puede que no patrocine ningún evento deportivo o que patrocine varios.

Pues bien tengo claro que "Evento" y "Entidad" son entidades relacionadas pero luego se habla de una entidad nueva que se llama "Patrocinador" de la cual no se nombra ningún atributo pero que tiene relación con las entidades "Evento" y "Entidad", el caso es que no se si meter una relación asociativa o una ternaria..

Tengo muchas dudas sinceramente, me tiene despistado.

Un saludo!

Comment: Hola, yo que tu haría las cosas lo más simple posible. Si una *entidad* organiza un *evento* entonces dicha *entidad* es el patrocinador. Punto. No te inventes cosas que compliquen las relaciones. Por como te plantean el ejercicio es una relación *n:n*. O al menos eso entiendo yo. Y recuerda siempre usar el *principio* [KISS](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_KISS) cada vez que puedas. Saludos

Comment: Efectivamente estaba dándole mas vueltas de las que requería y complicándolo mas.Gracias por tu aportación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El modelo ER de Chen viene muy bien para aclarar este tipo de cuestiones. Lo que pasa que has tenido la mala suerte de que tus organizadores y patrocinadores se llamen `entidades` y las vincules mediante relaciones, que en el modelo ER se llaman así pero, en Access, la relación es otro concepto (la FK o clave ajena). Vamos que tienes la confusión de nombres servida. Y si además tuvieras que lanzar un procedimiento almacenado periódicamente (a lo que curiosamente llamamos evento) pues ya tendrías la tormenta perfecta.

Vamos al modelo ER:

- sólo tienes dos entidades: `entidades` y `eventos`
- sólo tienes dos relaciones: `patrocinan` y `organizan`, que ni son lo mismo ni se modelan igual. Patrocinar es poner dinero y organizar implica mucho más, además de la restricción por cardinalidad que comentas.

Fíjate en que las entidades son nombres y las relaciones verbos; esta simplificación suele ayudar bastante.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te lo paso en SQL para que veas como la relación `organizan` no será necesario implementarla como una tabla, sino que será un campo de `eventos`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
CREATE TABLE entidades(
  id_entidad int AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  codigo varchar(31) UNIQUE,
  nombre varchar(31),
  web varchar(127)
  );
CREATE TABLE eventos(
  id_evento int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_entidad int,
  evento varchar(31),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_entidad) REFERENCES entidades(id_entidad)
  );
CREATE TABLE patrocinan(
  id_patrocinador int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_entidad int,
  id_evento int,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_entidad) REFERENCES entidades(id_entidad),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_evento) REFERENCES eventos(id_evento),
  UNIQUE(id_entidad,id_evento)
  );
```

Comment: En un principio lo tenia como tu me has puesto,pero como bien dices los nombres usados me han creado muchas dudas,Coincido 100% contigo,muchísimas gracias por la explicación que aclara mucho mas las cosas.